# Форвардинг логов с помощью rsyslog c cохранением всех метаданных (structured data и т.п.), как?

Tags: администрирование, rsyslog

Есть софт, который по UDP отправляет в rsyslog записи лога, в которых есть метаданные (название модуля и т.п. см. structured data). В конфиге rsyslog прописаны шаблоны пути и формата с использованием значений метаданных (т.е. например разложить по папкам от модулей и т.п.). Это работает как ожидается.

Нужно перебросить лог далее по ТСР. Правило добавлено и логи уезжают на нужную машину, но похоже модуль omfwd сам форматирует сообщение и передает далее без метаданных. И на машине назначения уже правила по ним не работают.

Направить напрямую логи софта на удаленную машину не хочется, по UDP оно локально шлет, хочется использовать очередь в omfwd и доставку с помощью TCP.

Возможно использовать такую связку? Может есть альтернатива omfwd?

Answer (score 0):

Поспешил с вопросом )
Ответ прост, но пусть будет.

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html

> **rawmsg**
>   the message “as is”. Should be useful for debugging and also if a message should be **forwarded totally unaltered**.

Т.е. просто в экшене форварда указываем шаблон с rawmsg

```
$template RawFormat,"%rawmsg%"
*.* action(type="omfwd" target="127.0.0.1" port="514" protocol="tcp" action.resumeRetryCount="100" queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000" template="RawFormat")
```